# How can I complete my dropdown with database data?

Tags: php, database, slim

I'm building an application based on Slim Framework, and I already have some working code. To return a JSON response with a list of projects, I wrote the following:

**Controller class** (`controllerProyectos.php`)

```
<?php
require "transferController/transferProyectos.php";
class NombreProyecto {
    public function getProyectos() {
        $list = array();
        foreach ($this->fillObject() as $sKey => $oValue) {
            $list[] = array(
                'id' => $oValue->getId(),
                'nombre_proyecto' => $oValue->getNombre(),
                'state' => $oValue->getState(),
            );
        }
        return $list;
    }
    private function fillObject() {
        $aObjects = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $oTransfer = new TransferProyeCtr();
            $oTransfer->setId($i);
            $oTransfer->setNombre("proyecto " . $i);
            $oTransfer->setState(1);
            $aObjects[] = $oTransfer;
        }
        return $aObjects;
    }
}
```

**Front controller** (`index.php`)

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
$sPathApi = "/api/sistemaTareas/";
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get($sPathApi . $sVersion . 'proyectos', function () { 
    require "controller/controllerProyectos.php";
    $oProyecto = new NombreProyecto();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($oProyecto->getProyectos());
    exit();
});
```

**Model class** (`transferProyectos.php`)

```
<?php
class TransferProyeCtr {
    private $sNombre;
    private $iId;
    private $iState;

    public function getNombre() {
        return $this->sNombre;
    }
    public function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->sNombre = $nombre;
    }
    public function getId() {
        return $this->iId;
    }
    public function setId($Id) {
        $this->iId = $Id;
    }
    public function getState() {
        return $this->iState;
    }
    public function setState($state) {
        $this->iState = $state;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using some mockup data in the controller. When I do an AJAX request to my application, I get the following result in a dropdown:

```
- proyecto 1
- proyecto 2
- proyecto 3
- proyecto 4
- proyecto 5
```

So far everything is working as expected. But I'd like to return real data from the database in that controller.

I wrote a function (inside `bdconnection.php` file) to open the database connection:

```
<?php
function connect_db() {
    $server = 'localhost'; 
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '123asd';
    $database = 'bd_actividades';
    $connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $database);
    return $connection;
}
```

I think that in my controller I need something like:

```
public  function getPro() {
    require "sistema/bdconnection.php";
    $sql = "select pro_nombre FROM act_proyecto";
    try {
        $db = connect_db();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($users);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And replace `$oTransfer->setNombre("proyecto " . $i);` for `$oTransfer->setNombre($users);`, but I'm not sure.

Just to give you guys a little more detail about my application, here will go the files structure and database data:

[image: Files structure and database data]

Comment: Hi, @Jean. Your question is kind of confusing and too broad. You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask. Anyway, have you already solved your problem? If so, please add the solution as an answer to your own question. This way you can help others.